# RAM and MMU requirement in ARM 11

Tags: arm

[ARM 11](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/classic/arm11/index.php) is based on Powerful ARMv6 instruction set architecture. 
But I am not able to figure out if it has;

1-MMU

2-Sufficient RAM for porting Linux

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 8):

ARM11 is an architecture. It [contains an MMU](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/I1002400.html). The ARM architecture itself doesn't have any RAM at all, that is dependent on the Chip you use (for an example I will assume an i.MX31 which uses the ARM11 core) and the amount of RAM you can interface via its memory controller. I know that the i.MX31 supports 256 MB (maybe eben more). Therefore this should be enough for a Linux installation.

You won't port Linux by yourself to such a chip, as this will usually be done by the chip vendor (or some subsidiary). Freescale (the vendor of the i.MX31) provides a board support package for [both Linux and Windows CE](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX31&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab) (see section Run-Time Software). Of course, you are free to make improvements or changes to that basic board support package.

Comment: you mean the SDRAM required by  CPU for booting kernel is not an on-chip RAM?

Comment: Also why you said Linux porting is done by the chip vendor  when linux kernel is freely available?

Comment: Yes, (DDR-)SDRAM is typically attached as an external chip via the on-chip memory controller (there are some exceptions but those are essentially chip-on-chip packages inside one single package); Linux porting is done by the chip vendor because this can be quite a lot of work - why would you want to do it on your own, if it's already available?